# How to remove the extra commas from the list of email addresses

Tags: python, string

I am using python and have a string of email addresses as shown below.

```
email_addr = 'test@domain.com, test1@domain.com, test2@domain.com'
```

Above string looks good, however some time i received the data that have blank email addresses in them.

For e.g.

```
email_addr = ' , , test@domain.com, test1@domain.com, , , ,test2@domain.com
```

I am using `str.split(',')` and lot of errors checking. Wondering if is there a better way to do this?

Final value i am expecting from:

```
email_addr = ' , , test@domain.com, test1@domain.com, , , ,test2@domain.com
```

to:

```
email_addr = 'test@domain.com,test1@domain.com,test2@domain.com'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for regular expressions. Use `.split(',')` to split into a list of strings.

```
email_lst = email_addr.split(',')
```

Then join with comma, but filter out blank values

```
email_addr2 = ",".join(e.strip() for e in email_lst if e.strip())
# 'test@domain.com,test1@domain.com,test2@domain.com'
```

In Python 3.8+, you can use the walrus operator to avoid calling `.strip()` twice:

```
email_addr2 = ",".join(e for ee in email_lst if (e := ee.strip()))
```

Comment: Nice, i would prefer this solution. +1

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```py
import re

email_addr = " , , test@domain.com, test1@domain.com, , , ,test2@domain.com"

email_addr = email_addr.replace(" ", "").strip(",")
email_addr = re.sub(r",{2,}", ",", email_addr)
print(email_addr)
```

Prints:

```
test@domain.com,test1@domain.com,test2@domain.com
```

Comment: while this is a good strategy, I suspect `.replace(" ", "")` is fraught with peril around bad inputs

Comment: @ti7 it's probably safe for a regex that just matches multiple commas in a row.

Answer (score 3):

I'd be quite tempted to validate as you go and rely on [`email.utils.parseaddr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.utils.html#email.utils.parseaddr) which will somewhat ensure email clients will accept them

```py
>>> parse_email_addr("Foo Bar <foo.bar@example.com>")
('Foo Bar', 'foo.bar@example.com')
```

```py
from email.utils import parseaddr as parse_email_addr
email_addr = ' , , test@domain.com, test1@domain.com, , , ,test2@domain.com'
result = ",".join(filter(None, (parse_email_addr(email)[1] for email in email_addr.split(","))))
# 'test@domain.com,test1@domain.com,test2@domain.com'
```

I'd also be tempted to account for bad fields, which may represent some input error (ie. how did you get these? should they be correct as inputs to your program?)

```py
>>> result
'test@domain.com,test1@domain.com,test2@domain.com'
>>> email_addr.rstrip(",").count(",") - result.count(",")
5
```

Answer (score 2):

If we use regex, how about getting a list of matches with `[^, ]+` and then joining all the items?

`[^, ]` means any char except `,` and  , and `+` means "1 or more"

```
import re

email_addr = " , , test@domain.com, test1@domain.com, , , ,test2@domain.com"

email_cleaned = ",".join(re.findall("[^, ]+", email_addr))

print(email_cleaned)
```